# What is the proper way to test if checkbox is ticked on scanned document?

Tags: c#, image-processing, omr

Let's assume, that we're scanning test-like documents with checkboxes / empty circles (for signing / striking / ticking). What would be the proper way, to check, if already cropped checkbox/circle is checked/signed/striked/ticked?
In case we'll force test users to fully mark the area, just knowing the position of checkbox/circle and counting amount on non-white pixels would be enough (would it?), but what way should we approach to test, that the checkbox / circle is ticked or checked (X)?
This is going to be part of the project in C#, so code or even ready libraries for .net / c/c++ would be appreciated.

Comment: The most robust way to do this would probably be with character-recognition software, much of which is neural-network based.

Comment: @anaximander: I don't think that's a good idea. There are no characters to recognize here. I could make an X, a full circle, fill it completely, etc.

Comment: There are some libraries - but they are commercial... is that an option for you ?

Comment: @Yahia: Yes, commercial libraries are an option, but it's heavily cost-related - how much dev time would it take to write "a way to do it" versus "what are the costs of incorporating X into the software". Unfortunately for me, from what I've seen, the SDKs for form processing / OMR are quite costly.

Comment: @mrówa yes they are costly but basically spending 1-3K (USD) is much less than the time it requires to writing a **robust** solution oneself...

Comment: @DanielHilgarth Perhaps "symbol recognition" would have been a better term. The concept is still sound - you're trying to determine which of a set of images are empty boxes and which has a symbol. If multiple images are not boxes, you're trying to determine which is a selection mark and which is a deletion or invalid mark. This is a classic neural-net OCR problem. Also, it's worth noting that many test papers intended to be marked by computers have instructions stating how to mark an answer and how to delete an incorrect answer, to limit the range of symbols that the system needs to recognise.

Comment: How you detected the exact position of checkbox in the scanned document?

Comment: @AkashdeepSaluja In the end I didn't create it. We've changed the tech to use already existing solution - queXF (in php/mysql) - it uses prescanning of empty forms to locate checboxes and it supports some OCR for texts, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

sorry for the shortness of this answer but you could have an ocr system run on the area within the checkbox.

If it returns nothing then you know it's not checked.

If it returns something then compare it against a large white list of possibilities and then flag uncertainties.

you could use the error handling that @dan proposed as well

What makes this more robust than just taking an average is that you can determine if it's not checked with a high certainty. because we're looking for a mark that is in some minimal way recognizable we know if there isn't anything there then it's definitely not checked. all you have to do then is find a good white list of characters and marks that could be used as checks (and think outside of the box, the ocr system may return an 'a' for a squiggle, but that is a positive response). And to clarify, the problem with just taking an average is that any increase in darkness in the check box yields a positive result, which isn't always the case. if someone puts a mark and then erases you're still going to have a increase in darkness within the box.

Lastly i'll add that there are a lot of OCR systems out there now that are pretty advanced. i doubt you'd have much trouble finding one where you could provide additional training data sets that would match you're cases better than random characters.

Answer (score 1):

The algorithm would go something like this:

1. Find each checkbox (I understand you already have that)
2. Calculate the average of the color of all pixels
3. If it is above a certain threshold, it is marked, if below, it is unmarked

However, you should add some checks:

- Are multiple above the threshold? -> Let a human check it, the student could have first ticked something and then changed it to another field.
- Are none above the threshold? -> Let a human verify that really none have been checked.

I guess the important part about this answer is:
If the algorithm is unsure, flag it for manual processing.

Comment: what about pages with different background colors? or even worse there is a gradient or image background for the page?

Comment: @DavidWork: Shouldn't be too hard: Get a clean sheet and calculate the average value of each checkbox. Subtract that value from the average value of the scanned test that is supposed to be filled out. I guess that would give even better results, because every non-checked checkbox should now have a value around 0 (scanned average - original average) = 0 + ERROR_MARGIN

Comment: There may also be cases where the student tries to erase or scratch out their answer (or put any non-affirmative mark in the check box) that would cause false positives. I think this solution leaves out the "proper" requirement

Comment: @Letseatlunch: I think "scratch out" is handled by the error handler for multiple checkboxes that are over the threshold.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth i think you're over estimating your "error handling". like how many times on a test did you not erase at least once? they'd have to manually review every test! I also agree with the background color issues, especially if there is a dark background color with light color checks then you'd need to take the average and see if it is under a threshold rather than over.

Comment: @Letseatlunch: That sounds like a bit of a stretch. The OP stated himself that he wants to count the number of *white* pixels., so the background is not dark. It's white. But you are free to post a better solution / algorithm. And you won't be able to do this without manual error handling. The review process can be really painless: Show only the checkboxes of the line that's unclear and let the user select the correct one. A thing of a few seconds.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth i'd go with an ocr solution, something like anaximander suggested and you so quickly dismissed

Comment: @Letseatlunch: I don't think that can ever work for the reasons stated in my comment to this suggestion.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth just have the ocr system run on the area within the checkbox and if it returns nothing then you know it's not checked. if it returns something then compare it against a large white list of possibilities and then flag uncertainties.

Comment: @Letseatlunch: I still don't think that this works better than my proposed solution. But this discussion is really pointless unless one of us is going to actually build this, because we can only guess. I won't build such a system, so I will stop discussing now :)

Comment: I've actually forgot that error handling for multiple choices in the project (oh my), but the application was meant to let the "operator" review every scan, as he still have to do some manual setting for every page. I'm not sure how counting the pixels would actually turn out in practice, as the scan results are raster images and one might turn out with two scans of the same page with "slightly" moved page and quite different dark pixels count (I'd need to test it first).

Answer (score 1):

Most of the high performance products that offer checkbox recognition use some kind of bell distribution curve to work out the likelihood of a box actually being checked: too much 'data' and there's a good chance the user changed their mind and has scribbled-out this box; too few and it could be the 'tail' left by a user ticking a box below and not lifting the pen before crossing the next box region.

I'd suggest you apply additional logic to deal with more than one box being allowed (e.g. do you own a car / do you also own a bike) as well as the situation where only one box can be correct (e.g. are you male or female). This should help your app. filter out the more obvious errors.